# KarmaJS not working with node >= 0.12.x

Tags: phantomjs, gulp, karma-runner, gulp-karma

I have recently upgrade to the latest version of node and have run into an issue getting Karma to work.  I am using Gulp and this is an Angular application.

In order to get as far I have, I had to

1. reference the v1.0.0-0 tag of karma runner from their repo since, 1.0.0 is not published in NPM yet

   `"karma": "git@github.com:karma-runner/karma.git#v1.0.0-0",`
2. Fork the following repos to remove `karma@>=0.9` from their `package.json` since I was getting NPM `peerDependencies` errors

   - https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher
   - https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor
   - https://github.com/thescientist13/karma-junit-reporter
   - https://github.com/thescientist13/karma-html2js-preprocessor

So now when I run my test tasks, the process runs, but there are no errors.  Locally I use karma-chrome-launcher, and while the browser opens, the tests never run, and the Chrome instance shows a 404 for a karma.js file, that's it.

For my coverage task, which runs phantomjs, the tasks starts and finishes but doesn't complete.

`$ gulp test:coverage
[21:45:07] Using gulpfile ~/Workspace/analogstudios.net/repo/as-webapp-2.0/gulpfile.js
[21:45:07] Starting 'test:coverage'...
[21:45:07] Finished 'test:coverage' after 40 ms`

In both cases I have to manually terminate the process.

Any thoughts?  Anyone tried getting Karma to work with Node 0.12.x?  I had been using Node 0.10.x with Karma 0.13.9 and had no issues.

These are the relevant packages in my `package.json`

    `"jasmine-core": "2.3.4",
    "karma": "git@github.com:karma-runner/karma.git#v1.0.0-0",
     "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.0"
    "karma-coverage": "0.5.1",
    "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "git@github.com:thescientist13/karma-html2js-preprocessor.git#186501615f93fa1bbc32f76e9960b7755a67151b",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.6",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "git@github.com:thescientist13/karma-junit-reporter.git#c9fa2d20085faf9393a746cba183b1b2c9c8d0f7",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "git@github.com:thescientist13/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor.git#0dcb89a705f9f3bee8dafb842533504135a95af7",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "git@github.com:thescientist13/karma-phantomjs-launcher.git#6ee01b8ded328f63dc1f79f53b95d356b3452d72",
    "phantomjs": "1.9.18",`